# Can't able to call method from multiple classes in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests

I am trying access method from two classes in another class but only one class method is called. during call of another class method it gives NullpointerException error. Please give me solution.

Code is here--->

Setup class-->

```
    package BasePOI;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Setup {

    public  WebDriver driver;

    public  void Websiteopen() {

        driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.get("url");

    }

    public Setup(WebDriver driver){


        this.driver=driver;

    }

}
```

Login page object class--->

```
    package BasePOI;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class LoginPOI  {

    public  WebDriver driver;




         //home
         By home_login=By.linkText("Login");
        By about_us=By.linkText("About Us");

        //login
        By counselor=By.id("counselor_login");
        By user=By.id("user_login");
        By username=By.id("username");
        By password=By.id("password");
        By Login=By.name("Login");
        By create_account=By.name("Login");

        By Logout=By.linkText("Logout");


        public LoginPOI(WebDriver driver){


            this.driver=driver;

        }

        public  void click_Login_button(){

            try {

            driver.findElement(home_login).click();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                System.out.println(e);
            }

        }

        public void click_Login_counselor(){

            driver.findElement(counselor).click();


        }

        public void click_Login_user(){

        driver.findElement(user).click();


    }



        public void Enter_login_data(String uname,String pwd){

            driver.findElement(username).clear();
            driver.findElement(username).sendKeys(uname);

            driver.findElement(password).clear();
            driver.findElement(password).sendKeys(pwd);


        }


        public void click_Login(){

            driver.findElement(Login).click();


        }



}
```

Now i am calling both classes method in another class

Login functionlity class--->

```
 package Functionlity;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import BasePOI.LoginPOI;
import BasePOI.Setup;



public class Login  {



    public WebDriver driver;



    @Test
    public void openwebsite() throws InterruptedException{



        Setup a= new Setup(driver);
        a.Websiteopen();

        Thread.sleep(10000);

        LoginPOI b=new LoginPOI(driver);
        b.click_Login_button();

    }
```

}

Here website method is running but click_Login_button method gives me

errorerror--->

> java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: can't able to call method from multiple classes in selenium webdriver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error is because  the `driver` under LoginPOI class is not initialized. Change your code as per below and try -

1. Setup Class

   ```
   package BasePOI;
   import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

   public class Setup {

       public  static WebDriver driver;

       public  void Websiteopen() 
       {

           driver = new FirefoxDriver();
           driver.manage().window().maximize();
           driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
           driver.get("url");
       }

       public Setup(WebDriver driver)
       {

           this.driver=driver;
       }
       public Setup()
       {
       }
       public WebDriver getDriver()
       {
           return this.driver;
       }

   }
   ```
2. Login POI

   ```
   package BasePOI;
   import org.openqa.selenium.By;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

   public class LoginPOI  
   {
        public  WebDriver driver;

        //home
       By home_login=By.linkText("Login");
       By about_us=By.linkText("About Us");

       //login
       By counselor=By.id("counselor_login");
       By user=By.id("user_login");
       By username=By.id("username");
       By password=By.id("password");
       By Login=By.name("Login");
       By create_account=By.name("Login");

       By Logout=By.linkText("Logout");


       public  void click_Login_button(){

           try {
               this.driver=new Setup().getDriver();
           driver.findElement(home_login).click();
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               System.out.println(e);
           }

       }
       public void click_Login_counselor()
       {
           driver.findElement(counselor).click();
       }
       public void click_Login_user()
       {
           driver.findElement(user).click();
       }
       public void Enter_login_data(String uname,String pwd)
       {
           driver.findElement(username).clear();
           driver.findElement(username).sendKeys(uname);
           driver.findElement(password).clear();
           driver.findElement(password).sendKeys(pwd);
       }
       public void click_Login()
       {
           driver.findElement(Login).click();
       }
   }
   ```
3. Login Class

   ```
   package Functionlity;

   import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
   import org.openqa.selenium.By;
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
   import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
   import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
   import org.testng.annotations.Test;

   public class Login  
   {
       public WebDriver driver;
       @Test
       public void openwebsite() throws InterruptedException
       {
           Setup a= new Setup(driver);
           a.Websiteopen();
           LoginPOI b=new LoginPOI();
           b.click_Login_button();

       }
   }
   ```

**Explanation :**

1. First need to make webderiver static under Setup class to make same driver accessible to different instances
2. create one default constructor in setup class and one method  which return driver to access in another classes
3. `this.driver=new Setup().getDriver();` will get the (initialized driver instances in setup class) driver in LoginPOI class

Comment: Thanks narendra. problem is solved. I am new on stack so can't able to add reputation.

Answer (score 0):

You are not initializing the driver object in your test class and that's why it throws null pointer exception when calling any webdriver method inside Page class.

The simple solution would be to modify your setup class and initialize the webdriver in setup method

**Setup class**

public class Setup {

```
public Webdriver getDriver() {
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("url");
}

public Setup(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver=driver;
}}
```

**Test Class**

public class Login  {

```
public WebDriver driver;

@BeforeMethod
public void setup() {
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}

@Test
public void openwebsite() throws InterruptedException{
    Setup a = new Setup(driver);
    a.Websiteopen();
    LoginPOI b=new LoginPOI(driver);
    b.click_Login_button();

}}
```